# Adding Object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In an Application it has Data Access layer.In which it has DataEntityModel.edmx  (entityframework model)  and repository class.

[image]

Below code is my repository class.

```
namespace DataModel.Repository
{
 public class ProductRepository
 {
    internal WebApiDbEntities Context;
    internal DbSet<Product> DbSet;

     public ProductRepository(WebApiDbEntities context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<Product>();
    }

    public virtual void Insert(Product entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

}
```

}

> Question is I have used **DbSet.Add(entity)** method to insert . But Entity Framework will generate it's own Add method **Context.Products.Add(entity)**
>
> So, What is the difference between those two methods. Why Most of the
>   time **DbSet.Add(entity)** is used ??

Answer (score 3):

A repository replaces the use of the DbContext.

So to add an entity, *instead* of:

```
var dbContext = new WebApiDataModel();
dbContext.Products.Add(entity)
```

You use a repository:

```
var dbContext = new WebApiDataModel();
var productRepository = new ProductRepository(dbContext);
productRepository.Insert(entity);
```

In the end, *both* call `DbSet<Product>.Add()`, but there are reasons why you may want to introduce the repository pattern with Entity Framework.

Comment: my question is with in the productRepository.Insert() method we can call dbContext.Products.Add(entity) method. But why we use  DbSet.Add(entity) rather than  dbContext.Products.Add(entity) ?

Comment: Yes, you can use either. Someone (not you, apparently) decided to introduce the repository pattern. You use that to abstract away the use of DbContext. So yes, you can use both, but you should choose either.